# How to create a static html doc with swagger?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a Spring Boot Rest API where I have integrated Swagger Maven dependencies. When I hit http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html I can access the Swagger UI.

My question is: what are the steps to create a HTML static view of this Swagger UI in the same way? Is there any way to do it just by adding few Maven dependecies and `index.html` will create like the UI page creates?

Comment: That static file is already generated and served to you in the browser. Check the resources directory, you should have it there

Comment: @maljukan it is not there that's why I made this question

Comment: At my job, some other teams are using Swagger, but each or generating the swagger.json (api definition) differently, and each are serving it up differently.  I too am looking for the swagger-ui.html file.  I'm sure it's **there** but I haven't installed the right package.

Comment: @userIllyrian, what would be useful (to me) is if you would state what you've tried and provide links to how you set up swagger, and the "maven dependencies" you are referring to.  And I see you have a rep of 1, so welcome aboard to SO (Stack Overflow).  Feel free to edit your question to add this information.